# Pagination in Django with two Querysets formatted in different ways

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset

I want to get pagination to work with two separate query sets that are formatted in different ways. The first query set is smaller and will never be longer than the first page. The second query set is very long and will go on for 5 or 6 pages. The result content of both query sets are the same, but I format them in different ways in the html template.

The models are exactly the same, Book and PremiumBook, except PremiumBook has lots more books (and contains all the elements in Book).

I'll include the views.py and then the template:

```
def servicesListView(request, category):
    model = Books
    table = Books.objects.filter(category=category)
    values_books = table.filter().values_list("serviceid")
    # remove these observations from next table. My next table is premium and not available to non-authenticated users
    new_table = PremiumBooks.objects.filter(category=category).exclude(bookid__in=values_books)
    new_table = new_table.filter().annotate(price_count=Count('premiumcost__price')).order_by('-price_count')[:60]
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(new_table, 5)
    try:
        new_table = paginator.page(new_table)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        new_table = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        new_table = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'services/index.html', {'table': table, 'new_table': new_table})
```

Then, this is the template for the them:

```
<main class="ui-book-list"> 
    <div class="results-list grid-view">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Book list </h2>
            <div class="grid-results-list book-list">
                {% for book in table %}
                        <div class="record">
                            <div class="content">
                                <h6>
                                    {{ book.easy_desc }}
                                </h6>
                                <div class="group">
                                    <div class="category">
                                        <span>Category:</span> {{ book.category }}
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="divider"></span>
                                    <div class="code">
                                        <span>Barcode:</span> {{ book.code }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                {% empty %}
                {% endfor %}

                {% for book in new_table %}
                    <div class="premium-user">
                        <div class="record">
                            <div class="content">
                                <div class="premium-tag" onclick="openPremiumModal()"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i>Premium User</div>
                                <a class="link" onclick="openPremiumModal()">
                                    <h6>
                                        {{ book.desc_us }}
                                    </h6>
                                </a>
                                <div class="group">
                                    <div class="category ">
                                        <span class="">Category:</span> {{ book.category }}
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="divider"></span>
                                    <div class="code ">
                                        <span class="">Barcode:</span> {{ book.code }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}

#this is my pagination stuff for one table, not sure how to do it for combined table
                {% if new_table.has_other_pages %}
                    <ul class="pagination mt-5 pagination-sm justify-content-center">
                        {% if new_table.has_previous %}
                            <li class="page-item">
                                <a
                                    class="page-link"
                                    href="?page={{ new_table.previous_page_number }}{% if request.GET.csrfmiddlewaretoken %}&csrfmiddlewaretoken={{ request.GET.csrfmiddlewaretoken }}{% endif %}{% if request.GET.s %}&s={{ request.GET.s }}{% endif %}">
                                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        {% else %}
                            <li class="page-item disabled">
                                <span class="page-link">
                                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                        {% endif %}

                        {% if new_table.number|add:'-4' > 1 %}
                        <li class="page-item">
                            <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ new_table.number|add:'-5' }}{% if request.GET.csrfmiddlewaretoken %}&csrfmiddlewaretoken={{ request.GET.csrfmiddlewaretoken }}{% endif %}{% if request.GET.s %}&s={{ request.GET.s }}{% endif %}">&hellip;</a>
                        </li>
                        {% endif %}

                        {% for i in new_table.paginator.page_range %}
                            {% if new_table.number == i %}
                                <li class="page-item active">
                                    <span class="page-link">{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span>
                                </li>
                            {% elif i > new_table.number|add:'-5' and i < new_table.number|add:'5' %}
                                <li class="page-item">
                                    <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}{% if request.GET.csrfmiddlewaretoken %}&csrfmiddlewaretoken={{ request.GET.csrfmiddlewaretoken }}{% endif %}{% if request.GET.s %}&s={{ request.GET.s }}{% endif %}">{{ i }}</a>
                                </li>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}

                        {% if new_table.paginator.num_pages > new_table.number|add:'4' %}
                            <li class="page-item">
                                <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ new_table.number|add:'5' }}{% if request.GET.csrfmiddlewaretoken %}&csrfmiddlewaretoken={{ request.GET.csrfmiddlewaretoken }}{% endif %}{% if request.GET.s %}&s={{ request.GET.s }}{% endif %}">&hellip;</a>
                            </li>
                        {% endif %}

                        {% if new_table.has_next %}
                            <li class="page-item">
                                <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ new_table.next_page_number }}{% if request.GET.csrfmiddlewaretoken %}&csrfmiddlewaretoken={{ request.GET.csrfmiddlewaretoken }}{% endif %}{% if request.GET.s %}&s={{ request.GET.s }}{% endif %}">
                                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        {% else %}
                            <li class="page-item disabled">
                                <span class="page-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            </li>
                        {% endif %}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you would like to happen?

Comment: You want a select list of non-premium books on your page but then want to paginate the premium books?

Comment: I want to list basic books first, then premium books next. Premium books will have a lock on it and only logged on users can access the Premium books. It will be formatted differently as premium books will have a lock on them and redirect to the login page.

Comment: Is it not easier to have a single `Book` model that has a `premium` boolean column. Then in your list view you just just filter the books by the matching category

Comment: When you render the books, if they are premium you add the logic to "lock" them

Comment: Thats a good idea, thank!

Comment: The only difficulty is implementing the sorting. Both query sets are sorted, especially the last one. How do I sort each group, Premium is True and Premium is False.

Comment: You need the premium books to be at the bottom? On pages 2, 3, 4 should the premium books appear?

Comment: Yes, I want premium books after all basic books (basic never fills a full page). Then I want to further order Premium books (since there are thousands) by an annotate by counts of numbers of books under a given title.

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 different `QuerySets` even paginated by different amounts like so

```
regular_books_query = Books.objects.filter(category=category)  # plus whatever
premium_books_query = Premium.objects.filter(category=category)  # plus whatever

regular_paginator = Paginator(regular_books, 10)
premium_paginator = Paginator(premium_books, 5)

page = request.GET.get('page')

regular_books = regular_paginator.get_page(page)
premium_books = premium_paginator.get_page(page)

return render('template.html', {
    'regular_books': regular_books,
    'premium_books': premium_books
})

Now whenever you go to the next page you will get the next page in both queryset
```